# Bootstrap 4 Collapsible Card - Choppy Animation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have created a card with a .card-header and .card-block like so:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="card-block">
        card block
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click the card header to toggle the card block. I've tried using Bootstrap's collapse mechanism (you'll notice the `data-toggle="collapse"` in the card header). It works - but the animation is extremely choppy.

I can't figure out why. [Here's an example on codepen](http://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/pjQeWr).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Laggy problem:**

The problem is the **.card-block** class, it adds a padding of 1.25rem by default.

If you would remove the class card-block from the div#test-block, and create a div inside with the class card-block (so you keep the padding you require), the laggy problem will go away.

**Clicky problem:**

There is no class with collapse on your #test-block, so it needs to add it first. That's why it works on the second try.

If you add a class with the name "collapse" to div#test-block, your laggy problem will go away.

If you want the panel to be opened by default, add the "in" class too. e.g. "collapse in".

I have the following code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-block">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Also it would be useful to add `collapse in` class to get block already opened by default.

Comment: That did it! I set the .card-block to padding: 0, and added a div.card-block-content to stick the padding on instead.

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov - if you want it open by default, yes true. In my case I actually don't.

Answer (score 3):

That probably why bootstrap 4 is still in alpha. It will probably be fix.

The only solution I found is to collapse your `card-block` by adding the class `collapse`, and then removing his padding by css :

```
.card-block{ padding:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The #test-block has the default state:

```
    <div id='test-block' class='card block'>
```

When clicked once the class changes to the expanded version of

```
    <div id='test-block' class="card-block collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
```

So the div does not have the correct default state. Change the state to reflect the `collapse in` and `aria-expanded=true` and it should require only 1 click.

I have no idea why the animation is choppy. :(